# How to show limited data in two different components in angular 2

Tags: angular

For example

I have made on shared component called image gallery in which all images are shown from json. Now i am using this shared component in home page and in gallery page. In home page i want to show first 8 images and in gallery page i want to show all images.

Shared Component

```ts
@Component({
selector: 'app-gallery',
templateUrl: './gallery.component.html'
})
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {
 //getting images data from my service

}
```

Html is of shared component is

```ts
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" *ngFor="let image of gallery">
  <div class="gallery-img">
    <a href="">
      <img src="{{gallery.images[0]}}">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Home page component html

```ts
<app-gallery></app-gallery> //Here i want show 8 images only
```

Gallery component page

```ts
<app-gallery></app-gallery> // Here i want to show all images from gallery
```

Comment: Can you post code of your component?

Comment: What is shared component, what is it's selector, where is it used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Input property in your app-gallery component:

```
@Input() images: any[];
```

And pass in any array of images from parent component:

```
<app-gallery [images]="images"></app-gallery>
```

or pass only first 4 images using Slice pipe:

```
<app-gallery [images]="images | slice:0:3"></app-gallery>
```

Here's basic [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DDyh2Tc7uunJXTNLtFPJ?p=preview) which might help to understand how to do this.

Comment: The advantage of using the `slice` pipe is that it's only called when the `images` array changes, while the `.slice()` method is called every time change detection runs, which can become quite expensive.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks for that, wow, didn't know about slice pipe. Very convenient! Will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use your components selector in home & gallery page , these both will be having different instances of shared component.

and for detecting which component this shared component belongs, you can pass string value as input value as below.

```
<shared_component [hostComponent]="homePage"></shared_component>
<shared_component [hostComponent]="imageGallery"></shared_component>
```

Now, inside shared component you can determine if hostComponent is "HomePage" then apply pipe to restrict images to 8 else don't apply the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the slice pipe

```ts
<shared-component [images]="images | slice:0:8"></app-gallery>
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/SlicePipe-pipe.html